# Matching multiple groups in string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like `'testname=ns,mem=2G'`

After parsing the above string I want 
to assign a variable `tstnm` to `ns` and variable `memory` to `2G`

```
import re
str = "testname=ns,mem=2G"

b = re.search('(?<=testname=)\w+', str)
m = re.search('(?<=mem=)\w+', str)
if b:
     tstnm = b.group(0)
if m:
     memory = m.group(0)
```

which works , but then when I tried to do it in one go , like -

```
m = re.search('(?<=testname=)(\w+)\,(?<=mem=)(\w+)', str)
```

`m` is `None` //

Answer (score 4):

Use `re.findall()`, and you can merge your regex using `pipe(|)`:

```
>>> s = "testname=ns,mem=2G"
>>> re.findall('(?<=testname=)\w+|(?<=mem=)\w+', s)
['ns', '2G']
```

Don't use `str` as variable name.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are using [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). They do only match a position, but not the string inside the groups. So, with `\,(?<=mem=)(\w+)` you are creating a regex that can never be true, because `\,(?<=mem=)` is always false.

You could use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) instead:

```
import re
input = "testname=ns,mem=2G"

result = re.search('testname=(\w+),mem=(\w+)', input)
if result:
     tstnm = result.group(1)
     memory = result.group(2)
```

Comment: +1: Never use lookarounds if capturing groups will do the job.  Beginners tend to reach for lookarounds first, and just end up making their problems more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Should you be using regex for this? How about simple string operations

```
inputString = "testname=ns,mem=2G"
result = inputString.split(",")
tstnm  = result[0].split("=")[1]
memory = result[1].split("=")[1]
print tstnm, memory
```

**Output**

```
ns 2G
```

Comment: That assumes that both variables will always be "declared" in the string and always come in that order (with nothing ahead of them). Given the if check for the first solution, I wouldn't say that's a fair assumption.